# Form field with Min and Max price

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, mysqli

Good day guys i have this code that select min and max price, when I assign value it doesn't filter
Here is the HTLM form

```
<form>
    <select class="custom-select my-2 border-left" id="price" name="price">
    <option value="">Max Price</option>
    <option value="60000">&#8358; 60,000</option>
    <option value="100000">&#8358; 100,000</option>
    <option value="500000">&#8358; 500,000</option>
    <option value="1000000">&#8358; 1 Million</option>
    <option value="2000000">&#8358; 2 Million</option>
    <option value="3000000">&#8358; 3 Million</option>
    <option value="4000000">&#8358; 4 Million</option>
    <option value="5000000">&#8358; 5 Million</option>
    <option value="10000000">&#8358; 10 Million</option>
    <option value="20000000">&#8358; 20 Million</option>
    <option value="40000000">&#8358; 40 Million</option>
    <option value="60000000">&#8358; 60 Million</option>
    <option value="80000000">&#8358; 80 Million</option>
    <option value="100000000">&#8358; 100 Million</option>
    <option value="150000000">&#8358; 150 Million</option>
    <option value="200000000">&#8358; 200 Million</option>
    <option value="300000000">&#8358; 300 Million</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This is the Search result page

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
$price="%{$_POST['price']}";

$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where productPrice BETWEEN '60000' AND '300000000'");

?>
```

There is a table called `productPrice`, but how can user search base on min and max price

Comment: Your form's `method` attribute is not set so it defaults to `get` - thus `$_POST['price']` will not be available

Comment: am really consign about this $con,"select * from products where productPrice BETWEEN '60000' AND '300000000

Comment: What i did is just to copy part of the code i already have the form method in place

Comment: Well you don't have it in the code you posted. What's the use of showing code that's not the code you're actually using? What about `$price`, what's with the `%`? Where are you using `$price`? Inside a code you didn't post?

Answer (score 0):

First I think that you need one more form, to specify the minimum value in the same form, because they'll send together for php code on server side.

```html
<form action="url_to_yourfile.php" method="POST">
    <select class="custom-select my-2 border-left" id="price" name="min-price">
    <option value="">Min Price</option>
    <option value="60000">&#8358; 60,000</option>
    <option value="100000">&#8358; 100,000</option>
    <option value="500000">&#8358; 500,000</option>
    <option value="1000000">&#8358; 1 Million</option>
    <option value="2000000">&#8358; 2 Million</option>
    <option value="3000000">&#8358; 3 Million</option>
    <option value="4000000">&#8358; 4 Million</option>
    <option value="5000000">&#8358; 5 Million</option>
    <option value="10000000">&#8358; 10 Million</option>
    <option value="20000000">&#8358; 20 Million</option>
    <option value="40000000">&#8358; 40 Million</option>
    <option value="60000000">&#8358; 60 Million</option>
    <option value="80000000">&#8358; 80 Million</option>
    <option value="100000000">&#8358; 100 Million</option>
    <option value="150000000">&#8358; 150 Million</option>
    <option value="200000000">&#8358; 200 Million</option>
    <option value="300000000">&#8358; 300 Million</option>
    </select>

    <select class="custom-select my-2 border-left" id="price" name="max-price">
    <option value="">Max Price</option>
    <option value="60000">&#8358; 60,000</option>
    <option value="100000">&#8358; 100,000</option>
    <option value="500000">&#8358; 500,000</option>
    <option value="1000000">&#8358; 1 Million</option>
    <option value="2000000">&#8358; 2 Million</option>
    <option value="3000000">&#8358; 3 Million</option>
    <option value="4000000">&#8358; 4 Million</option>
    <option value="5000000">&#8358; 5 Million</option>
    <option value="10000000">&#8358; 10 Million</option>
    <option value="20000000">&#8358; 20 Million</option>
    <option value="40000000">&#8358; 40 Million</option>
    <option value="60000000">&#8358; 60 Million</option>
    <option value="80000000">&#8358; 80 Million</option>
    <option value="100000000">&#8358; 100 Million</option>
    <option value="150000000">&#8358; 150 Million</option>
    <option value="200000000">&#8358; 200 Million</option>
    <option value="300000000">&#8358; 300 Million</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then, in PHP you can:

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  error_reporting(0);
  include('includes/config.php');
  $min_price=addslashes($_POST['min-price']);
  $max_price=addslashes($_POST['max-price']);

  $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where  productPrice BETWEEN $min_price AND $max_price");
?>
```

Comment: what of "min-price" value

Comment: @EzekielChimkwanum you have said this "code that select min and max price" right!? But in your code there is no input for select the minimum value to it is sending after to backend php code. So, I've created this input with the name min-price, but could be whatever name you want, like "min-value" for example.